# How to do a form with steps in Laravel?

Tags: php, forms, session, laravel

I'm trying to create a "Step-by-step" form with Laravel. The trouble I'm having is how to let the user go "back" and edit the previously submitted part of the form.

I'm doing the regular validation stuff, here's an example of the form field:

`{{ Form::text('title', Input::old('title') }}`

Then, if the form for that particular step passes validation, this will be saved in a session as an array and the user will be taken to the next part of the form.

Want I want to have is a "back" button on each step where they can go back to the previous step an change it. The problem is that I have `Input::old()` for the value parameter of the input.

One thing I could do is assign a variable like "current" and set that to the session for that particular step, so my syntax for the inputs would look like this:

`{{ Form::text('title', (!empty($current)) ? $current['title'] : Input::old('title')) }}`

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 6):

ShawnMcCool's Form Base Model provides a good mechanism for both handling input values without the need for ugly ternaries, and also support for multipage forms.  I'll not list any code here, instead recommend that you read through the bundle's examples:

https://github.com/ShawnMcCool/laravel-form-base-model#examples

Answer (score 1):

I might have a multi dimensional array with the input from each page stored under page number.

```
$saved = Session::get('inputtedstuff');
$current = $saved['page1'];
```

Then whichever page you are on you can grab that pages previous answers if there are any. And at the end you can get all the answers together and map them to a flat array for further use.

I would also, depending on the complexity of the form, consider doing the form all in one page and use javascript to show each part. Just a thought.